# R keep data frame attributes after join

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to keep data frame attributes after some joins. It seems that `dplyr` functions holds attributes from columns but not the ones from the data frame itself.

See the example below:

```
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")


#Fake data
n = 20
df <- data.frame("user_id" = 1:n,
                 "type" = sample(c(1,2), n, replace = T),
                 "amount" = 1000*rnorm(n))

#Suppose I want to add some metadata
attr(df, "query_timestamp") <- lubridate::now()
attr(df$amount, "currency") <- "BRL"

#encoding table for user type
encode <- data.frame("type" = c(1,2), 
                     "description" = c("vendor", "shopper"))

print(attr(df, "query_timestamp"))
```

> [1] "2018-07-18 15:30:57 -03"

```
print(attr(df$amount, "currency"))
```

> [1] "BRL"

```
df <- df %>% dplyr::left_join(encode, by = "type")
print(attr(df, "query_timestamp"))
```

> NULL

```
print(attr(df$amount, "currency"))
```

> [1] "BRL"

Is there any reason for that? I would like to keep attributes but avoid using aux variables to store them.

Comment: `?now` returns: "No documentation for ‘now’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??now’"

Comment: I'm sorry. `now()` is from `lubridate` package. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "reattach" the attribute using the `attr<-` function:

```
df <- df %>% dplyr::left_join(encode, by = "type") %>% 
                         `attr<-`("query_timestamp", attr(df,"query_timestamp") )

> print(attr(df, "query_timestamp"))
[1] "2018-07-18 14:41:39 PDT"
```

Normally the call would be one of:

```
`attr(df, "query_timestamp") <-  attr(df,"query_timestamp") )
# or equivalently
`attr<-`(df, "query_timestamp", attr(df,"query_timestamp") )
```

But as you probably know the first argument can be dropped if it is the object that is being processed. This way you reattach before the destructive assignment (`<-`) is executed. So you need to either save the attribute before the join as a separate value and then reattach it in a separate step after the join, or do it this way (reassigning just before the destructive "back"-assignment.

Comment: you could use `attributes` which is vectorized

Comment: Yes, but it would be `attributes<-`.