# R: How to keep Date format in using "Join" function in r ? Here is the toy code and data

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Despite reading several topics as listed bellow, I did not find my answer:

[R keep data frame attributes after join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409001/r-keep-data-frame-attributes-after-join)

[Merging two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941677/merging-two-data-frames)

[How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

I have two txt files containing Year, Month, Day, and two types of weather info (precipitation, and minimum temperature):

[image]

[image]

You could download these two simple txt files here:

[sample_txt_data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oj1c98bxvm2flto/sample_txt_data.zip?dl=0)

I try to join these two data frames using this code:

```
library(dplyr)
setwd("C:/Users/Climate_Data")

Alberta_Pr <- read.csv("pr_day_Alberta.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t") 
head(Alberta_Pr)

Alberta_Tasmin <- read.csv("tasmin_day_Alberta.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
head(Alberta_Tasmin)

Joined_data <- full_join(Alberta_Pr, Alberta_Tasmin, by = c("Year", "Month", "Day"))
head(Joined_data)
```

**But using full_join function, remove zeros from month and day columns:**

[image]

**How can I keep the data as it is?**

Yours comments or answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Its easier to help you if you provide some sample data with `dput()`

Comment: There seems to be confusion about the internal representation of numbers and how they are formatted in R. For example, consider `x <- 1:3`; you can format them with a leading zero using e.g.  `sprintf("%02i", x)`. When you read in your data with `read.csv`, R automatically tries to guess the format of entries in the different column. In your case, it seems that columns `Month` and `Day` become `num` (or `int`). To *print* them in a particular format (e.g. using leading zeros), you need to use `sprintf` (or `formatC`).

Comment: PS. Take a look at this useful post [How to add leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/how-to-add-leading-zeros)

Comment: You *could* use `read.csv` and prevent R from guessing column types by explicitly specifying `colClasses = "character"`. In that case all columns would be `character` vectors. I would advise against this though, as it makes *working* with the data more difficult (e.g. it requires you to convert `character` vectors to `num`/`int` vectors manually if you wanted to do some calculations involving `Month` and `Day`).

Comment: So in short: The join (seems to have) worked. The issue is with understanding the difference between how data are stored and shown in R.